# Why should I use tf.data?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm learning tensorflow, and the tf.data API confuses me. It is apparently better when dealing with large datasets, but when using the dataset, it has to be converted back into a tensor. But why not just use a tensor in the first place? Why and when should we use tf.data?

Why isn't it possible to have tf.data return the entire dataset, instead of processing it through a for loop? When just minimizing a function of the dataset (using something like tf.losses.mean_squared_error), I usually input the data through a tensor or a numpy array, and I don't know how to input data through a for loop. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The `tf.data` module has specific tools which help in building a input pipeline for your ML model. A input pipeline takes in the raw data, processes it and then feeds it to the model.

> When should I use `tf.data` module?

The `tf.data` module is useful when you have a large dataset in the form of a file such as .csv or .tfrecord. `tf.data.Dataset` can perform shuffling and batching of samples efficiently. Useful for large datasets as well as small datasets. It could combine train and test datasets.

> How can I create batches and iterate through them for training?

I think you can efficiently do this with NumPy and `np.reshape` method. Pandas can read data files for you. Then, you just need a `for ... in ...` loop to get each batch amd pass it to your model.

> How can I feed NumPy data to a TensorFlow model?

There are two options to use `tf.placeholder()` or `tf.data.Dataset`.

1. The `tf.data.Dataset` is a much easier implementation. I recommend to use it. Also, has some good set of methods.
2. The `tf.placeholder` creates a placeholder tensor which feeds the data to a TensorFlow graph. This process would consume more time feeding in the data.